# How to find joint cdf

Tags: probability

Let $~X~$ and $~Y~$ be continuous r.v. with a joint Pdf:

$$ f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 2(x+y) & ; 0\leq x\leq y\leq 1\\
0 & ; \text{else}
\end{cases} $$

Can someone explain how to find the joint CDF of this problem?

Also can someone please explain to me how to evaluate the bounds to integrate cdf and how to create the piecewise of joint cdf.

I’m stuck on this joind cdf and marginal cdf.

Comment: The probability density function is given by $F(s,t)= \int_{ (-\infty,s] \times (-\infty, t]  } f(x,y)dxdy$. Drawing where the density function is supported should help.

Comment: Ruby, any questions?

Comment: Is that it? The key answer on the book shows the CDF on piecewise and that’s why I’m confuse

Comment: Feel free to show the answer.

Comment: F (x,y) : 0  if x<0 or y<0 ; xy^2 +x^2y-x^3 if 0<=x<=y<=1 ; y^3 if x>y and 0<y<1 ; x+x^2-x^3 if y>1 and 0<x<1 ; 1 if x>1 and y>1

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Firstly we can use that $0\leq x\leq y\leq 1$ is equivalent to $x\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq x\leq 1$

Then $$P(X\leq a, Y\leq b)=\int_0^a \left(\int_x^b 2(x+y) \, dy \right) \, dx $$

$$P(X\leq a, Y\leq b)=\int_0^a \left(b^2+2bx-3x^2\right) \, dx =...$$

Comment: Canu you explain it more specific?